# arrays program in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, do-while

I am supposed to write a program that could accept user input of aircraft name, destination, number of passengers and flight time. The user is asked if how many aircrafts he/she would like to process. I know that I should make use of arrays. Here's my current codes but it stops after the input of the first aircraft name.

here's what's happening:

> Enter airline company: French Air
>   Enter number of aircrafts to process: 3
>   Enter aircraft name: ABC
>   Enter destination: Tokyo
>   Enter number of passengers: 156
>   Enter flight time: 10:15
>   Enter aircraft name: DEF
>   Enter destination: Chile
>   Enter number of passengers: 88
>   Enter flight time: 11:00
>   Enter aircraft name: FGH
>   Enter destination: Miami
>   Enter number of passengers: 157
>   Enter flight time: 12:00
>
> Today's report of international fligts forFrenchAir
>
> AIRCRAFTS DESTINATION NUMBER OF PASSENGERS    FLIGHT TIME
>   ABC   Tokyo   156 10:15
>   DEF   Chile   88  11:00
>   FGH   Miami   157 12:00
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>       at AircraftsReport.main(AircraftsReport.java:54)

Here my current codes:

```
import java.util.*;

public class AircraftsReport 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String airline = "";
        String strAircraft = "", strDestination = "", strFlightTime = "";
        int passengersCount = 0, num2process = 0, ctr = 0, ctr2 = 0;

            System.out.print("Enter airline company: ");
        airline = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter number of aircrafts to process: ");
        num2process = input.nextInt();

        String[] AIRCRAFTS = new String[num2process];
        String[] DESTINATIONS = new String[num2process];
        String[] FLIGHT_TIME = new String[num2process];
            int[] PASSENGERS_COUNT = new int[num2process];

        while(ctr < num2process)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter aircraft name: ");
            strAircraft = input.next();
            AIRCRAFTS[ctr] = strAircraft;

            System.out.print("Enter destination: ");
            strDestination = input.next();
            DESTINATIONS[ctr] = strDestination;

            System.out.print("Enter number of passengers: ");
            passengersCount = input.nextInt();
            PASSENGERS_COUNT[ctr] = passengersCount;

            System.out.print("Enter flight time: ");
            strFlightTime = input.next();
            FLIGHT_TIME[ctr] = strFlightTime;

            ctr++;

        }


        System.out.println("Today's report of international fligts for" +
                        airline);

        System.out.println("\nAIRCRAFTS\tDESTINATION\tNUMBER OF PASSENGERS" +
                "\tFLIGHT TIME");

        for(ctr2 = 0; ctr2 <= AIRCRAFTS.length; ctr2++)
        {
            System.out.print(AIRCRAFTS[ctr2] + "\t" + DESTINATIONS[ctr2] + 
                    "\t" + PASSENGERS_COUNT[ctr2] + "\t" + FLIGHT_TIME[ctr2]);
            System.out.println();

        }

    }

}
```

Please help with figuring out what's wrong

It produces the output together with the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at AircraftsReport.main(AircraftsReport.java:54)

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you observe instead of making us read that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
int passengersCount = 0, num2process = 0, ctr = 0, ctr2 = 0;
```

you declare `num2process` as 0.

So the next line

```
String[] AIRCRAFTS = new String[num2process];
```

creates an array of 0 length.

A few lines after that you reassign `num2process`:

```
num2process = input.nextInt();
```

but this won't change the size of the previously created array.

You enter the `do while` loop once (because they always get executed at least once), and the condition check subsequently fails

```
} while(ctr < AIRCRAFTS.length);
```

because `ctr` is 1 at this point (after executing `ctr++;`) and `AIRCRAFTS.length` is still 0.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend an Aircraft object instead of separate lists of all those items.  Java's an object-oriented language.  It's better to encapsulate related attributes into a single class and use that.

```
public class Aircraft {
    private String aircraft;
    private String destination;
    private Date departureTime; 
    private int maxPassengers;

    // You add the rest.
}

// and this in your main    
public Aircraft [] aircrafts = new Aircraft[numAircraft];
```

But if that's too advanced for you, I'd recommend learning how to read exceptions:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 at AircraftsReport.main(AircraftsReport.java:54)
```

Open AircraftsReport.java in a text editor and turn on line number display.  Go to line 54 - that's where your error is.

This code works.  I'd recommend studying it to see why:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * AircraftsReport description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900443/arrays-program-in-java/13900477#comment19154335_13900477
 * @since 12/16/12 6:33 AM
 */
public class AircraftsReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String airline = "";
        String strAircraft = "", strDestination = "", strFlightTime = "";
        int passengersCount = 0, num2process = 0, ctr2 = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter airline company: ");
        airline = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter number of aircrafts to process: ");
        num2process = input.nextInt();

        String[] AIRCRAFTS = new String[num2process];
        String[] DESTINATIONS = new String[num2process];
        String[] FLIGHT_TIME = new String[num2process];
        int[] PASSENGERS_COUNT = new int[num2process];

        // changed this
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < num2process; ++ctr) {
            System.out.print("Enter aircraft name: ");
            strAircraft = input.next();
            AIRCRAFTS[ctr] = strAircraft;

            System.out.print("Enter destination: ");
            strDestination = input.next();
            DESTINATIONS[ctr] = strDestination;

            System.out.print("Enter number of passengers: ");
            passengersCount = input.nextInt();
            PASSENGERS_COUNT[ctr] = passengersCount;

            System.out.print("Enter flight time: ");
            strFlightTime = input.next();
            FLIGHT_TIME[ctr] = strFlightTime;
        }


        System.out.println("Today's report of international fligts for"+
                airline);

        System.out.println("\nAIRCRAFTS\tDESTINATION\tNUMBER OF PASSENGERS"+
                "\tFLIGHT TIME");

        // changed this
        for (ctr2 = 0; ctr2 < AIRCRAFTS.length; ctr2++) {
            System.out.print(AIRCRAFTS[ctr2]+"\t"+DESTINATIONS[ctr2]+
                    "\t"+PASSENGERS_COUNT[ctr2]+"\t"+FLIGHT_TIME[ctr2]);
            System.out.println();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you referring to as the rest in your comment? kindly answer please. Is that the void main part?

Comment: No - constructors, getters/setters, actual behavior that you might give to an Aircraft, equals, hashcode, toString, compareTo - methods.

Comment: Bro, i'm not that familiar with the objects thingy. My codes above produces the output but it has the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 at AircraftsReport.main(AircraftsReport.java:54) PLS HELP

Comment: I'm not your bro, and "objects thingy" will come if you last long enough.  That exception means you're trying to iterate past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialsing the value of num2process after you have defined the arrays. The size of the arrays is 0. Modify the code like this.

```
System.out.print("Enter airline company: ");
airline = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter number of aircrafts to process: ");
num2process = input.nextInt();

String[] AIRCRAFTS = new String[num2process];
String[] DESTINATIONS = new String[num2process];
String[] FLIGHT_TIME = new String[num2process];
int[] PASSENGERS_COUNT = new int[num2process];
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your code is that you are initializing a zero sized array and then asking the user to input num2process.
 this might do the trick

```
        System.out.print("Enter airline company: ");
        airline = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter number of aircrafts to process: ");
        num2process = input.nextInt();
         // Then initialize your arrays


        String[] AIRCRAFTS = new String[num2process];
        String[] DESTINATIONS = new String[num2process];
        String[] FLIGHT_TIME = new String[num2process];
            int[] PASSENGERS_COUNT = new int[num2process];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first dont initilize your arrays until you know how many num2process should be. Just looking at that your arrays are a size 0. Ask the num2process and then do your arrays. That will probably fix your problem. Because the loop is going through once and getting 0 back (because you initilized the arrays with 0 before you asked)